# Read the PDF response and display the PDF though ajax

Tags: ajax, pdf-generation, ajax.beginform

Issue is with displaying the PDF response as PDF in new tab. I am trying to do something like this:  Trying to hit a url\ gives the reponse something in        %PDF-1.4 1 0......%%EOF

Code I wrote is

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
  },


  success: function(data, status, xhr){

    var newWindow = window.open("", "new window", "width=200, height=100");
    newWindow.document.write(data); // displays the result in new window
  },
}
```

But the Output i am expecting is to view the PDF in the new tab. Not the result of the call in the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite difficult, but just because of the browser configuration. Some browsers (most of them), when you try to open a PDF in the current tab or in a new one just download it automatically, so, first you should take a look to your browser settings.
Once browser settings are correctly configurated I really suggest to open the PDF as the result of a form action and not with ajax. A form action with a target="_blank" will open the PDF in a new tab.

If that doesn't work because the browser still download the PDF and you need to display it on a new tab, I would create a view in html/css by passing all data you want to display and visually styled as the pdf. I would also include a "download" flat button or icon, that calls the creation and download the real PDF.

Hope this helps you.